# How to change the date format on a Work Item in Azure DevOps Work item

Tags: azure, date, format, devops

The date format on each Work Item is showing in US format (M/d/yyyy) and I need it to display in AU format (dd/mm/yyyy). I have set the region for the Organisation and set my own user profile to the correct browser language and date format, but it will not change. The problem occurs in (new) Edge and Chrome but IE is correct.

How can I get the correct date format to display?

Comment: were you able to get an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems this can be done by following

Select your project -> Click on the profile icon -> Click on the ellipsis (...) on the profile summary popup ->  Select **User Settings** on that popup -> Select **Time and Locale** on the next popup -> Go to the settings page and change region and date format.

TBH, it took me an hour to find this. Not a pleasant experience.

[image]

Comment: Please describe in text what your picture shows.